# How to get lines matched to special regex

Tags: regex, match

I want to get all lines which :

- begin with '- '

or

- contains '=' or '<' or '>'

i get all lines which begin with `'- '` by `r"^- .*"` and all lines which contains '=' or '<' or '>' by `.*[=<>]` but i don't know how to combine the expression.

You find my example here: 
https://regex101.com/r/pUk3qM/4/

Comment: Maybe `^([ -].*|.*[<>=].*)$`? See https://regex101.com/r/pUk3qM/5

Comment: Match the `-` at the start or match the operator `^(?:-|.*[<>=]).*$` https://regex101.com/r/kJYwK8/1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: That will match a string that starts with a space w/o any -.

Comment: @ScottHunter That is in line with the formerly closed OP question. If the space is not needed now, just remove it, `^(-.*|.*[<>=].*)$`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: That's nice but a) nowhere is that question referenced here and b) it isn't in line with *this* question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `(^- |[=<>])` if you don't care about the match - just need to know whether the whole line matches or not.

If you actually do need to match the whole line, you can use `^(- |.*[=<>]).*$` instead